# What is Android Automotive OS?

Tags: android-automotive

What is Android Automotive OS?
At Google I/O 2019, there was a session about building apps for Android for Cars and a new Automotive OS was mentioned. What is it? Does it run on user's Android phones? https://events.google.com/io/schedule/events/b57b960c-a05b-4f65-b739-b85e2613a405

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Automotive OS is a new variant of Android with its own platform, similar to how Android TV works. According to the official documentation:

> Android Automotive OS allows users to install stand-alone apps onto their vehicle’s infotainment system. These stand-alone apps must be driver-optimized and separate from your phone app.

Android Automotive OS has its own dedicated Play Store and apps targeting the platform must declare `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.automotive" android:required="true" />` in their manifest to be installable. For more information about adding support to existing apps for this new platform, see https://developer.android.com/training/cars#automotive-os-auto.

Answer (score 0):

No "Android Automotive OS" does not run on your phone.  It is installed on the vehicle by its manufacturer.  It is the car's built-in Infotainment System.

This is different from "Android Auto".  "Android Auto" runs on your phone, and allows you to project certain apps running on the phone onto the vehicle's infotainment display.  (Your phone connects to the car using a USB cable or Bluetooth.) For example, the Google Maps app running on your phone would display its maps on the vehicle's display.  Also you can use the cars's speakers to listen to music playing on the phone.  And you can use the car's microphone and speakers to use voice to interact with Google Assistant (also running on your phone).

Answer (score 0):

Android Auto is the Android Auto application running on the Android phone, and showing on the vehicle screen through the projection service implemented by the vehicle. Now Android Auto supports either wire or wireless projection.

Android Automotive is another android running on the vehicle to provide in-vehicle infotainment system. Like Android phone serves the telephony services through the RIL hardware abstraction interface, Android Automotive has its Vehicle HAL to talk to the vehicle to provide the controls or communications to the vehicle, such as HVAC controls. From the revealed Polestar 2, the Android Automotive will serve the Google Assistant voice control, google Maps for Navigation, and play store for application installation.